# How to link a dll, to an exe file in run-time?

Tags: c, dll, runtime.exec

I am new to programming and I created a dll project in which, i will just print a line. In the application project I have called the function defined in the dll project.

My question is, I am getting the dll file, soon after building the dll project. But when I build the main app, i.e., application project i am getting the following error.

```
--------------------Configuration: test_bench - Win32 Debug-------------------- 
Compiling...
main.c
Linking...
main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _print_dll
../../exec/test_bench.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
Error executing link.exe.

test_bench.exe - 2 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

If I link the obj before the build, it gets built. But if I change the code of dll project, again i have to re-build the main project, which should not be necessary while running a dll.

Please help me to achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a little binary *template* to help with dlopen related calls.  You'd need to tweak it for your specific use case (as it is, it only handles strings), but I have found it handy on many occasions.

Usage: `dlopener /path/to/library.extension function_name [args...]`

```
//gcc -rdynamic -o dlopener dlopener.c -ldl
#include <dlfcn.h> /*for dlopen,dlsym,dlclose*/

int main(int argc, char **argv){

   /* get a "handle" for a shared library*/
   void *handle = dlopen(argv[1], RTLD_LAZY);

   /* make sure we got a handle before continuing*/
   if (! handle) return 1;

   /*undefined, but workable solution : POSIX.1-2003 (Technical Corrigendum 1) */
   void* (*f)()=dlsym(handle, argv[2]);

   /*now call the function f(argv[3],argv[4],...argv[argc]); */
   //TODO convert args to unsigned char representations for other types 
   while (argc > 2)  /*ugh, have to use asm to preserve stack*/
      asm("push %0"::"r"(argv[argc--])); /*from right to left*/

   asm("call *%0"::"r"(f)); //TODO  "=a"(ret) where is uchar[XXX]

   /*remember that shared library we opened?*/
   dlclose(handle);

   return 0;
}
```

Note: for some WIN32 functions (cdecl calling convention IIRC) you need to use a different asm mechanism than push to get the values in registers instead of on the stack

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that you didn't link the library (DLL) in your executable, that's why it can't find the function `print_dll`.

You can load libraries dynamically in Windows through [LoadLibray()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx)

Here is a sample on how you do it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686944(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

For linking the `dll` project in run time, you need to implement the run time linking in your `main` file. If you implement the the run time linking means, no need to re-build the project every time.
 For run time linking you need the following functions

```
#include <dlfcn.h>

   void *dlopen(const char *filename, int flag);

   char *dlerror(void);

   void *dlsym(void *handle, const char *symbol); //symbol is your function name

   int dlclose(void *handle);

   Link with -ldl.
```

See the man page for more details.
but while changing your code, if you change the function name you should use the same name in the place of `symbol`.